# Magento ajax cart not deleting last product in cart?

Tags: jquery, magento

I'm having alot of trouble making this extension work with my shop. My problem is, that the last product in cart is not deleted. Or it is, but it's not updating when deleting the product. I've figured as much as this must be the part of the script that deletes the product, can anyone tell me if theres a way to make it "update" when deleting the last product? It's from AheadWorks Ajax Cart Pro.

```
function updateDeleteLinks(){
var tmpLinks = document.links;
for (i=0; i<tmpLinks.length; i++){
    if (tmpLinks[i].href.search('checkout/cart/delete') != -1){
        url = tmpLinks[i].href.replace(/\/uenc\/.+,/g, "");
        var del = url.match(/delete\/id\/\d+\//g);
        var id = del[0].match(/\d+/g);
        if (window.location.protocol == 'https:'){
            aw_base_url = aw_base_url.replace("http:", "https:");
        }    
        if(!AW_ACP.isCartPage){
            tmpLinks[i].href = 'javascript:ajaxcartprodelete("' + aw_base_url + 'ajaxcartpro/cart/remove/id/' + id +'")';
        }else{
            tmpLinks[i].href = 'javascript:ajaxcartprodelete("' + aw_base_url + 'ajaxcartpro/cart/remove/id/' + id +'/is_checkout/1")';
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out this took care of the problem. Also I cannot figure out what this piece of code does:

```
 else{
        tmpLinks[i].href = 'javascript:ajaxcartprodelete("' + aw_base_url + 'ajaxcartpro/cart/remove/id/' + id +'/is_checkout/1")';
    }
```